# How do you save the combination of an image and lines drawn on it? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image

I've got saving an image down, but whenever I draw lines on the image and try to save the image, the image doesn't save with the lines I drew on it. How do I go about saving the images with the lines drawn on it?

Here's the current code for drawing lines:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DrawClass: UIView {
    /*
    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */
    ///Creating an array of type Line which accepts a Line object. It is an empty array.
    var lines:[Line] = []
    var lastPoint: CGPoint!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.layer.zPosition = 1
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent){
        if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
            lastPoint =  touch.locationInView(self)
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent){
        if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
            var newPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
            lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end: newPoint))
            lastPoint = newPoint
        }
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextBeginPath(context)
        for line in lines
        {
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, line.start.x, line.start.y)
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, line.end.x, line.end.y)
        }

        var storage: Float = ViewController.simple.storage1
        var storage2: Float = ViewController.simple.storage2
        var storage3: Float = ViewController.simple.storage3

        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, CGFloat(storage), CGFloat(storage2), CGFloat(storage3), 1)

        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Sorry, I forgot to add in the saving method. By the way "earth" is the name of the image I placed in the storyboard Here it is:

```
@IBAction func saveImage(sender: UIButton) {


    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(earth.image!, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)

}

func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo:UnsafePointer<Void>) {
    if error == nil {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Your altered image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the method to save the image?

Comment: I'll add in the method when I get back home in 15 mins.

Comment: Alright I've added it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your current `saveImage` method implementation.

```
@IBAction func saveImage(sender: UIButton) {


    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(earth.image!, self, "image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:", nil)

}
```

All this does is to explicitly save just the image of the `UIImageView` instance `earth`.

To save them with the lines, you need to create a new image from the `earth` view, as follows:

```
     @IBAction func saveImage(sender: UIButton) {

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(earth.frame.size, earth.opaque, 0.0)
            earth.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
            let imageWithLines = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            // NOW you have the image to save
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageWithLines, self, Selector("saveComplete"), nil)
     }

     func saveComplete () {
         NSLog("Complete!");
     }
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just tried running it, but I'm getting a SIGABRT error. *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'ColourSwitcher.ViewController<0x7fded2d014c0> does not respond to selector image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:' At the end of the error it says "Uncaught exception"

Comment: I copy-pasted that line from your code assuming that you have a method with that name. To keep things simple, try my edited answer.

Comment: I tried it out then got this error, "ColourSwitcher[2068:50465] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSInvocation setArgument:atIndex:]: index (2) out of bounds [-1, 1]'"

Comment: Hold on. I think I'm on to something.

Comment: Okay, do note that the instance `earth` in my code should be of type `DrawClass`.

Comment: Ohhh. The code automatically used the earth image I made in the view controller class. How do I go about making the earth instance be of type DrawClass? Pretty new to this.

Comment: Also the save method is in my Viewcontroller class.

Comment: Thank you very much! I created a new instance of the DrawClass, exchanged the 'earth' instance with it then executed the code and it started functioning properly! Just 20 minutes ago, before the code started to function properly, I followed your code and it didn't function properly for some reason. Oh well, I probably made a typo somewhere. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool! Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

After drawing your lines, you can save the `UIImage` obtained from the current context.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *imageFromView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: You should be using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` for this and be passing in a scale of `0.0` to get the main screen scale.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell with only this code snippet and without your storyboard, but I would try:

placing the UIImageView inside of DrawClass in the storyboard and make an outlet to it. Then handle setting the image in initialisation. That way when you save you can just snapshot DrawClass (both the image and the lines)

How are you trying to save the image at the moment?

edit:

So rather than dragging in a UIImageView and setting an outlet, it would be easier to programmatically create a UIImageView once the UIImage is set.

So in your DrawClass implementation:

```
var image: UIImage! {
    didSet{
       imageView = UIImageView(frame: self.bounds)
       imageView.image = image
       self.addSubView(imageView)
       self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

var imageView: UIImageView!
```

then in your main viewController in viewDidLoad put:

```
drawCanvas.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")
```

Once your image is loading in your DrawClass view you can use Vinod's method for getting the image to be saved. 
I would recommend putting the save image code in DrawClass though, then you have a fully reusable class. So I think in DrawClass add a function:

```
func saveImage() {
    //Vinod's code to save
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, true, 0.0)
        self.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let imageWithLines = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        // NOW you have the image to save
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageWithLines, self, Selector("saveComplete"), nil)
 }

 func saveComplete () {
     NSLog("Complete!");
 }
```

Then in your main view controller in your saveImage func:

```
@IBAction func saveImage(sender: UIButton) {
        drawClass.saveImage()
}
```

Comment: Just a moment, I'll add it in soon.

Comment: Okay I've added it in.

Comment: Alright I'll see if I can do that. Will get back if I have any troubles.

Comment: Tried to put the image in the DrawClass but it won't become a reference to the ui image in the storyboard.

Comment: I was thinking about it this afternoon and I think a better solution anyways is to make the UIImageView programatically, that way you don't need to mess about with outlets... just a second I'll edit my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Thanks. Where do I put the first block of code in the DrawClass? I'm getting two errors which say "DrawClass does not have a member called view" .Sorry if the answer is obvious, but I'm pretty new to Swift.

Comment: sorry my bad, I gave you the wrong code!! I don't have my laptop with me so can't check it myself with Xcode. I think the new code (I edited my answer) should work

Comment: Have you made an outlet to the custom view in your main view controller?

Comment: No, not yet. Going to try it out now.

Comment: Okay I've made a new instance of DrawClass called drawClassInstance. When I try to use the code you told me to put in my DrawClass implementation, it gave me this error, "DrawClass does not have member called addSubView

Comment: Hmm, ok I'll make the class and get it working tonight/tomorrow morning. Sorry about that!